# NSUInteger to int

Tags: cocoa, printf, nsuinteger

I wrote a method tha uses myarray, defined in the same class. When I use count it always returns 0.
When I use:

```
printf("%d", [myarray count]);
```

compiler says:

```
Format '%d' expetcs type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'NSUInteger'
```

why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `%lu` instead of `%d`. The compiler checks your format string against the parameters that you are passing to `printf`, sees that you are passing an unsigned but print it as a signed integer, and issues a warning. The warning indicates that for numbers greater than or equal to 2^31 `printf` would output a large negative number, when the data type implies a different semantic, namely, a large positive integer.

**EDITED in response to comments by Josh Caswell and thepepp**

Comment: The [docs say](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW5) to use `%lu` for `NSUInteger`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell @theapp Thanks for the comments! I did not realize that the size of `NSUInteger` changes based on the platform setting. I edited the answer.

Comment: Not only should you use `%lu` but you should also cast your `NSUInteger` to `(unsigned long)`. Typically you'll find that omitting the cast is fine, but for strict correctness you should have it, and the [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1) guide tells you to perform the cast.